# What is making my car lose almost all power when accelerating?

Tags: nissan, stall

I recently put my 2002 Nissan sentra 1.8 back together from a head gasket job.  Upon starting the car, it idles just fine...but as soon as I put it in drive the rpms drop to about 550 and feels like it's about to stall.  Giving it gas smooths every thing out, until I go over 3000 rpm or if I press hard on the accelerator, which both send the car into a fit of shuddering and making backfiring-like noises until it stalls completely.  I also notice that my gas pedal is tight, or hard to depress.  Any ideas?  
Note: I've read that my maf sensor may have something to do with it, so I unplugged it, ran the car for a while and that just made it worse.plugging it back in brought the car back to "normal"...

Edit: I'm gonna run through that list of possibilities that zipzit provided and check back which the results.

Comment: Swapped spark plug wires?  One wire / spark plug not seated correctly?Cam shaft alignment to main crankshaft off by one notch on gear?

Comment: Funny you mention the camshaft being off by a notch because this is what I suspected it could be...but why would it only be evident when in gear?

Comment: Have you ever tried to laugh, cough, hiccup, sneeze and inhale a breath while drinking a glass of water?  Its kinda like that.

Comment: How so?  I don't understand.

Comment: Really? What do you think the cam shaft does? Timing matters. its not possible to simultaneously breath and drink water.  Human: Breathe, then drink, then breathe.  Engine: suck in air/fuel, compress, ignite & explode, evacuate exhaust.   How did you ensure Top Dead Center (TDC) alignment for the camshaft when reinstalling the engine? Can you insert a photo of the page from the repair manual you used into your question?

Comment: What was the problem that led you to change the head gasket in the first place @NathanielDavidson? It may be relevant now.

Comment: @zipzit sure, what page though...timing?

Comment: @GdD broken spark plug

Comment: @NathanielDavidson . What service book are you using?  Haynes or Chilton? If you didn't use a book or some other reference guide to exactly tell you exactly how to line up the cams with the crankshaft at Top Dead Center, you may well have gotten things out of alignment.  There may be some youtube stuff out there, but I'd sure start with the book.

Comment: I do see this [link from Autozone](https://www.autozone.com/repairguides/Nissan-Car-Altima-Sentra-1999-06/Engine-Mechanical-Components/Timing-Chain-Cover-Seal-Chain-Sprockets/_/P-0996b43f80381dc5) that may be helpful.  Perhaps you used this instead of a book?  Remember the Cam shaft spins at half the speed as the crankshaft.  You will need to understand how the valves work to ensure you are in a compression stroke.

Comment: Are you saying you had to tear down the engine to find a piece of spark plug @NathanielDavidson? That's more involved than a head gasket job, what level did you tear it down to? Were there any components replaced? What else did you do?

Comment: @zipzit im not sure who made the book I have it in PDF downloaded from the Nissan site.  Shows the position the cams should be in during installation

Comment: @GdD well I actually chose to replace the gaskets, since I didn't want to go through the trouble of cleaning up the ceramic debris so it won't fall into my cylinder(no air tools or vac).  I left the fuel injectors and intake bolted to the head, removed throttle body for cleaning, air box, exhaustmanifold, and cams.  The intake cam broke, so I ordered one from the dealership, and replaced all gaskets from the head-up.  A vac hose is cracked near maf but I don't think that could be causing this

Comment: I can't imagine what broke the intake cam, but it sure sounds like a cam timing issue to me.

Comment: A cracked and leaking vacuum hose could definitely make a car run erratic. Very inexpensive repair.  Did you reevaluate the cam shaft alignment?  What did you find?